# GEMM block matrix partitioning doesn't work on python

Tags: python, c, caching, matrix-multiplication

I am learning GEMM and I tried using cache block to optimize the performance.
Basically I implemented same code on C and Python.
Why isn't the performance improved on Python?(only calculating the time before and after the loop). Does python have different read and store mechanism on cache?

C code

```
int n = 512; // matrix size = 512*512

// basic matrix multiplication
void matrix(double **a, double **b, double **c){
  int i, j, k;

  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    for (j=0; j<n; j++)
      for (k=0; k<n; k++)
        c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
}

// cache blocking for matrix multiplication
void matrixV1(double **a, double **b, double **c, int block){
  int i, j, k, ii, jj, kk;

  for (ii = 0; ii < n; ii += block)
    for (jj = 0; jj < n; jj += block)
      for (kk = 0; kk < n; kk += block)
        for (i = ii; i < ii+block; i += 1)
          for (j = jj; j < jj+block; j += 1)
            for (k = kk; k < kk+block; k += 1)
              c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
}
```

Python code

```
## basic matrix multiplication
def matrix(A,B):
    ## m=r=n=512 if matrix size = 512*512
    m, r, n = len(A), len(A[0]), len(B[0])  
    C = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n):
            for k in range(r):
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
    return C

## cache blocking for matrix multiplication
def matrixV1(A, B, BLOCK=8):
    ## m=r=n=512 if matrix size = 512*512
    m, r, n = len(A), len(A[0]), len(B[0])  
    C = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
    for ii in range(0, m, BLOCK):
        for jj in range(0, n, BLOCK):
            for kk in range(0, r, BLOCK):
                for i in range(ii, ii+BLOCK, 1):
                    for j in range(jj, jj+BLOCK, 1):
                        for k in range(kk, kk+BLOCK, 1):
                            C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
    return C
```

Comment: These codes aren't the same; C loop iterates to limit `n` for the first three loops, while the python iterates over `m`, `n`, and `r`. Where does `n` come from?

Comment: @SteveFriedl. Sorry I forgot n. I've modified the code. n is defined as the global variable, which is the size of the matrix. I input the same 512*512 matrix so the n in C is equal to the m,r, n in Python, which is 512.

Comment: I don't know the GEMM algorithm at all, but this looks like it's going to do the inner loop on the order of 1.8 x 10^16 times, which is quite enormous. Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Where exactly are you "calculating CPU time"?

Comment: @SteveFriedl, It's matrix multiplication. I think it's 512*512*512.

Comment: @jwdonahue, I use "clock()" before and after loop to calculate how many time it spend in the loop. The performance is improved by C but not Python. I am curious about the reason.

Comment: You should [edit] you post and explain exactly what you are trying to do.  Also good to post an [mcve].

Comment: I would add that Python is unlikely to perform as well as C on almost all algorithm benchmarks.  Locality of memory will have a huge impact on how often the cache is flushed, and there are many other factors, too numerous to go into here.

Comment: Did you compile the Python code or run it through the interpreter?

Comment: @jwdonahue, thank you, I edit the post and code. I know python's performance is worse than C. But comparing to basic matrix multiplication, blocking doesn't improved any performance on python but it improved ~15% on C.

Comment: I didn't compile python code. I just use jupyter to test it.